# TSQL Check if Month and Year fields are expired

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table with Month and Year fields as integer, eg:

```
Month | Year 
------------
  10  |  17
------------
  11  |  17
------------
  12  |  17
------------
   1  |  18
------------
```

(Year 17 is for 2017 and Year 18 is for 2018)

I want add into a query a calculated field for check if the date is expired

```
SELECT [Year], [Month],
    CASE WHEN 
        ([Year]+2000) < DATEPART(Year, GetDate()) OR 
        (([Year]+2000) = DATEPART(Year, GetDate()) AND [Month] < DATEPART(Month, GetDate())) 
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsExpired
FROM test
```

the output is

```
Month | Year | IsExpired
------------------------
  10  |  17  |    1
------------------------
  11  |  17  |    1
------------------------
  12  |  17  |    1
------------------------
   1  |  18  |    1
------------------------
```

the expected output is (because current GetDate() is 2017-11-29):

```
Month | Year | IsExpired
------------------------
  10  |  17  |    1
------------------------
  11  |  17  |    0
------------------------
  12  |  17  |    0
------------------------
   1  |  18  |    0
------------------------
```

see live on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c807/2

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look closely at your sql fiddle. select * from test Then look closely at the values in Year and Month....they are backwards. But to be honest what you are truly doing wrong is storing portions of dates in separate columns. Instead use a single column with the date datatype and you don't have to jump through hoops to do date evaluations. If you put the right values in the right columns your code works fine.

Comment: @SeanLange oh thanks, i'm stupid... :D

Answer (score 0):

Convert your values to dates:

```
WITH IntDates AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (10,17),(11,17),(12,17),(1,18)) AS D ([Month], [Year])),
Dates AS(
    SELECT *,
       DATEADD(YEAR, [Year], DATEADD(MONTH, [Month], '20000101')) AS DateValue
    FROM IntDates)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN DateValue < GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Expired
FROM Dates;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the date datatype this becomes a lot simpler.

```
create table test2
(
    ExpirationDate date
)

--have to do a bunch of string manipulation to turn this into viable dates.
--and this of course is after switching the columns posted in your sql fiddle.
insert test2
select convert(char(4), [Year] + 2000) + right('0' + convert(varchar(2), [Month]), 2) + '01'
from Test

select case when ExpirationDate < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0) --get beginning of the current month
        then 1 else 0 end
    , ExpirationDate
from test2
```